# how to separate two non aligned column in unix with screenshot

Tags: unix

[image: desc]

Hi, I have two non aligned column, I want to print the first column.

Attached image of Unix terminal

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you need nothing but `awk`, using it this way:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' output2.txt
```

This will print both the TTL and the product description like this:

```
TTL CANNED MEAT
TTL CANNED MEAT CORE SEGMENTS
…
```

If you want only the TTL column:

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want to print the product description without the TTL:

```
awk '{print $2}'
```